# Incorrect syntax near keyword '.Unclosed quotation mark in stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have 2 tables and 2 stored procedures. In both stored procedures, I have the same code for inserting data.

From one stored procedure, I am getting an error while inserting same data.

Message : `Testing is going on. Let's find out it.`

I am passing a value from C# codebehind to the stored procedure directly.
I can not change in C#. I have to handle in SQL Server stored procedure only.

I tried to replace single to with double (`REPLACE(@message  ,'''', '''''')`), it pass value into table but added double quote. How to handle that

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcInsertRecord
    @Name VARCHAR(30),
    @mobile_no VARCHAR(30),
    @message VARCHAR(30),
    @Address VARCHAR(30),
    @Designation VARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table1 (Name, Mobile, Message, Address, Designation) 
    VALUES (@Name, @mobile_no, @message, @Address, @Designation)
END
```

Comment: Can you post your C# code as well please

Comment: No dear,I can't

Comment: will be difficult to help without seeing the code, but it sounds some some of the varchar values are being quoted to much

Comment: By the time any SQL code is running, the error has already happened. You can't fix this from the SQL side, you *have* to fix the calling C# code.

Comment: This looks like the value is passed in a sql command string. Please don't do that for the problem you found, and to prevent sql injection. The C# side *needs* to be fixed - by the time sql might get this value, the error has already happened